# How would I use variables in my mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use variables in my mysql statement so they will change depending on the input. For example if the user does not enter size, that part of the statement won't show up. Sorry I am bad at explaining. But when I run the code below, I get an error, but If I remove the 'dynamic' AND statements, the code works. I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong. And ideas.

```
        if($size2 ==''){
    $size_stat = '';
    }else{
    $size_stat = "AND size='$size2'";

    }

    if($re2 ==''){
    $re_stat = '';
    }else{
    $re_stat = "AND re='$re2'";

    }


    if($status2 ==''){
    $status_stat = '';
    }else{
    $status_stat = "AND status='$status2' ";

    }


    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT 
      lat,lng,id,re,re_num,name,city,state,zip,address,status,category,size,
      ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat2) ) 
                   * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
                   * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($long2) ) 
                   + sin( radians($lat2) ) 
                   * sin( radians( lat ) ) 
                   )
      ) AS distance 
    FROM 
      locations
    WHERE 
      (state='PA' OR state='NY') 
    .$re_stat. 
     $size_stat.  
     $status_stat. 
    HAVING 
      distance < 300
    ORDER BY 
      distance 
    LIMIT 
      0 , 50    ");

    while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){


    $array_json[] = $array;
    }


    echo json_encode($array_json);
```

Comment: missing whitesapec at a guess. e.g. $status_stat = " AND status='$status2' ";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have spacing issues with the AND statements.

For all your *_stat variables add a space at the beginning and at the end of the string so the sql query does not break.

For example:

```
$size_stat = " AND size='$size2' ";
```

Also, make sure you have spaces between the "WHERE" and "HAVING" clauses.

**UPDATE**: Also, check if the query is actually returning any results.

**UPDATE2**: Replace the dots '.' in your query with spaces...

Comment: What do you mean? I'm sorry if I am being dense

Comment: To all your *_stat variables?

Comment: Your quary is ...AND X = ?AND Y=?AND etc.. no spaces between and statements

Comment: @NicRoni You really need to give us abit more than that. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Well, it is saying that I $array_json is an undefined variable which I  believe is the mysql statement because when I take out the AND's, the code works

Comment: @NicRoni Have you tried doing a print_r($array) in the while loop? Could it be that the query returns nothing?

Comment: thats what I was thinking so I tried the query without variables in phpmyadmin, and it works perfectly

Comment: @NicRoni and how did you get the query to test it out in phpmyadmin?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8975/discussion-between-nic-roni-and-zaf)